# カスタム投稿タイプのカテゴリーページのパーマリンクについて

Tags: php, wordpress

`clothes`というカスタム投稿タイプを作り、`tops`, `bottoms` , `accessory` というカテゴリーに分けているとします。

それぞれのカテゴリーページのパーマリンクを `www.example.com/clothes/category/tops` のようにしたいのですが、やり方がわかりません。

ちなみにいまは `sidebar.php` のカテゴリー一覧のループは下記のようにしています。

```
<ul>
  <?php 
    $categories = get_terms('category');

    foreach($categories as $category):
      $cat_id = (int) $category->term_id;
   ?>
  <li>
    <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat_id); ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></a>
  </li>
   <?php 
    endforeach;
  ?>
</ul>
```

これでは `www.example.com/category/tops` となってしまいます。
テンプレートに親子関係を持たせたりするのでしょうか。